# How are DPs generally structured when just encapsulating a noun?

Tags: syntax, x-bar-theory

I often see a noun such as "Jimmy" in my textbook represented as [DP_Jimmy]. But there is no more detail provided as to its internal structure. This means either the D is null such as:
[image]

or that "Jimmy" is functioning as a D, represented as

[image]

I suppose, like many things in linguistics, this may vary depending on your framework--but which one is more acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper nouns when considered as DPs will be merged with a phonetically null determiner. We can make this specific by positing that certain phonetically null determiners bear a **uproper** feature, that is an uninterpretable proper feature. This means that these Ds will merge with NPs bearing the feature proper.

[image]

We can complicate this further if we assume a nominal shell structure for the NP Jimmy.